# Swift collect class array for value

Tags: swift, class, uitableview, dictionary

I have class array

```
class TrainerModel: NSObject {

var name: String
var items: [String]
var collapsed: Bool
var trainerNewsID: String

init(name: String, items: [String], collapsed: Bool = false, trainerNewsID: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.items = items
    self.collapsed = collapsed
    self.trainerNewsID = trainerNewsID
}
```

and add data to this array:

```
var trainerArray = [TrainerModel]()


 let firstItem = TrainerModel(name: "Name1", items: ["first", "second"], collapsed: false, trainerNewsID: "TestID")
 let secondtItem = TrainerModel(name: "Name1", items: ["third", "else", "test"], collapsed: false, trainerNewsID: "TestID2")
 let thirdItem = TrainerModel(name: "Name2", items: ["first", "second"], collapsed: false, trainerNewsID: "TestID3")

  trainerArray.append(firstItem)
  trainerArray.append(secondtItem)
  trainerArray.append(thirdItem)
```

And have 3 items in trainerArray
I want to put trainerArray inside UITAbleView section for trainerArray[indexPath.section].name

And all good, but I have 2 section with name "Name1" and "Name2"

I'm try to sort by name, but it did not help

How can I collect trainerArray for name? Example:

Now I have:

```
sectionName = "Name1"
  cells = "first", "second"
sectionName = "Name1"
  cells = "third", "else", "test"
sectionName = "Name2"
  cells = "first", "second"
```

I want to see:

```
sectionName = "Name1"
  cells = "first", "second", "third", "else", "test"
sectionName = "Name2"
  cells = "first", "second"
```

Comment: What about other fields like `trainerNewsID`?\

Comment: @PGDev, no I need to collect by name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TrainerModel {

    var name: String
    var items: [String]
    var collapsed: Bool
    var trainerNewsID: String

    init(name: String,
         items: [String],
         collapsed: Bool = false,
         trainerNewsID: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
        self.collapsed = collapsed
        self.trainerNewsID = trainerNewsID
    }
}

extension TrainerModel: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "name \(name); items \(items); collapsed \(collapsed); trainerNewsID \(trainerNewsID)"
    }
}

extension Array where Element == TrainerModel {
    func createNewWithMergedUniqueKeys() -> Array<TrainerModel> {
        var setOfKeys: Set<String> = []
        var dictOfIndicies: [String: Int] = [:]
        for index in 0..<count {
            let trainerModel = self[index]
            let name = trainerModel.name
            setOfKeys.insert(trainerModel.name)
            dictOfIndicies[name] = index
        }
        var resArray: [TrainerModel] = []
        for key in setOfKeys {
            var resSet: Set<String> = []
            filter { $0.name == key }
                .map { $0.items }
                .forEach { array in
                    array.forEach { resSet.insert($0) }
                }
            guard let index = dictOfIndicies[key] else {
                continue
            }
            let trainerModel = self[index]
            trainerModel.items = Array<String>(resSet)
            resArray.append(trainerModel)
        }
        return resArray
    }
}

    var trainerArray = [TrainerModel]()


    let firstItem = TrainerModel(name: "Name1", items: ["first", "second"], collapsed: false, trainerNewsID: "TestID")
    let secondtItem = TrainerModel(name: "Name1", items: ["third", "else", "test"], collapsed: false, trainerNewsID: "TestID2")
    let thirdItem = TrainerModel(name: "Name2", items: ["first", "second"], collapsed: false, trainerNewsID: "TestID3")

    trainerArray.append(firstItem)
    trainerArray.append(secondtItem)
    trainerArray.append(thirdItem)

    print(trainerArray.createNewWithMergedUniqueKeys())
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the `trainerArray` based on name using the `Dictionary's` **`init(grouping:by:)`**.

Create an `array` of `tuples` containing `name` and all `items` corresponding to that `name`.

```
var groupedTrainerArray = [(name: String, items: [String])]()
```

Now in `viewDidLoad()`, set the `groupedTrainerArray` like so

```
groupedTrainerArray = Dictionary(grouping: trainerArray, by: { $0.name }).map { (key, value) -> (String, [String]) in
    let items = value.flatMap({ $0.items })
    return (key, items)
}
```

Next, use `groupedTrainerArray` as `tableView's` `dataSource`.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return groupedTrainerArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return groupedTrainerArray[section].items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = groupedTrainerArray[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    //rest of the code...
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return groupedTrainerArray[section].name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your `trainerArray`:

```
// create a dictionary to collect the items by name
var dict = [String : [String]]()

// fill in the data
for trainer in trainerArray {
    dict[trainer.name, default: []] += trainer.items
}

// get the section titles from the sorted keys
let sectionTitles = dict.keys.sorted()

// create an array of values corresponding to the section title
let sectionValues = sectionTitles.compactMap { dict[$0] }

print(sectionTitles)
```

> ```
> ["Name1", "Name2"]
> ```

```
print(sectionValues)
```

> ```
> [["first", "second", "third", "else", "test"], ["first", "second"]]
> ```